# How to keep Rails controller RSpec test DRY when introducing a private method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Currently, we have one action defined within our controller, and we test it using RSpec. We now need to create a second action that needs to reuse most of the functionality contained within the first action.

Therefore, we will refactor this common code into a private method and then have both actions call the private method.

Question is, where do we test the functionality of this private method? Keep in mind that it is doing a lot of stuff.

I know we should never directly test private methods, but rather test the public interface which in turn will test the private method. Surely we would want to keep our specs DRY and not repeat all common functionality specs within each 'describe', would we?

**Example Class:**

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

    def action1
        ...
        # Do something unique to 'action1'
        ...
        my_object = ...

        do_some_common_stuff(my_object)
    end

    def action2
        ...
        # Do something unique to 'action2'
        ...
        my_object = ...

        do_some_common_stuff(my_object)
    end

    private
    def do_some_common_stuff(my_object)
        # Do something common 1
        # Do something common 2
        # Do something common 3
        # Do something common 4
        # Do something common 5
    end
end
```

**Example Test Spec:**

```
describe MyController do
    describe "POST 'action1'" do
        it "should do something unique to action1"

        it "should do something common 1" do
            some_object.should_receive(:a_call)
            post :action1
        end

        it "should do something common 2"
        it "should do something common 3"
        it "should do something common 4"
        it "should do something common 5"
    end

    describe "POST 'action2'" do
        it "should do something unique to action2"

        it "should do something common 1" do
            some_object.should_receive(:a_call)
            post :action2
        end

        it "should do something common 2"
        it "should do something common 3"
        it "should do something common 4"
        it "should do something common 5"
    end
end
```

As you can see this spec is not very DRY.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do a `shared_examples`.

```
shared_examples "common" do
  it "should do something common 1"
  it "should do something common 2"
  it "should do something common 3"
  it "should do something common 4"
  it "should do something common 5"
end
```

and use it in your spec

```
describe "POST 'action2'" do
  it_should_behave_like "common"
  it "should do something unique to action2"
end
```

You can see the documentation on rspec : https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: Not sure 'shared_examples' will work for my situation, because within each example of action1 I will do a 'post :action1' in order to execute the tests.

Comment: You just need add your post :action in the before

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- RSpec helper methods and modules, or
- RSpec custom matchers, or
- RSpec shared examples, or
- RSpec shared contexts

Refer [Different ways of code reuse in Rspec](http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2011/08/17/different-ways-of-code-reuse-in-rspec/).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* test the common stuff directly if you want to: extract it into a collaborating class, and test that class. Then stub out the collaborator in the controller test.

If you don't want to do that, then shared examples are likely the best choice. Note that shared examples are in effect parameterized by the context in which they are used:

```
shared_examples "common" do
  it "does something common" do
    subject.should be_whatever
  end
end

describe "POST 'action1'" do
  subject { post :action1 }
  it_behaves_like "common"
end

describe "POST 'action2'" do
  subject { post :action2 }
  it_behaves_like "common"
end
```